# Counting a row in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database

If I have a table which looked something like

```
(`id`, `category`, `content`, `post_time`)
```

And I wanted to count the categories WHERE (for example) post_time > '1326600000'
I want the data to be displayed something like this:

```
categorys['cat_1'] = 4
categorys['cat_2'] = 2
categorys['cat_3'] = 1
```

The only way I can think of doing this is getting every row in MySQL.
Create a list of categories.
Then do a count(id) as cat_count WHERE category = 'category_from_list'

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a better way?

Yes:

```
SELECT category,
       COUNT(1)
  FROM insert_table_name_here
 WHERE post_time > '1326600000'
 GROUP
    BY category
;
```

(MySQL actually makes the GROUP BY clause optional — if you select both `category` and `COUNT(1)`, it will infer the GROUP BY clause — but you should include it anyway.)

Comment: Wow thanks. So simple but exactly what I wanted.
Sorry I'm so bad at SQL =(

Comment: @LeeJacobson: You're welcome! Don't feel bad; SQL is a huge beast, and it can be really hard to find the feature you're looking for if you don't already know what it's called.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `category`,
       COUNT(`category`) as TotalCount
FROM `tableName`
WHERE post_time > '1326600000'
GROUP BY category
```